# Can one mixin rely on another?

Tags: dart

I'm trying to create a mixin that manages some `AnimationController`'s in Flutter, but in order to create an animation we must provide it a `TickerProvider`. Normally this would be provided by another mixin, `TickerProviderStateMixin`.

This forces me to cast the mixin instance in order to make it work:

```
mixin MultiAnimationStateMixin on State {
...
    _anim1 = AnimationController(vsync: this as TickerProviderStateMixin);
...
}
```

This seems brittle. Is there no way to define to `MultiAnimationStateMixin` that it should require the `TickerProviderStateMixin`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way:

```dart
mixin MultiAnimationStateMixin on State, TickerProvider {
  ...
  _anim1 = AnimationController(vsync: this);
  ...
}
```

Having two (or more) types in the `on` clause means that the mixin must be applied to something which implements *both* (or all) interfaces.